# Diode code of the first one: **B23 INF** meaning

Tags: diodes, identification

Diode marked by code:

B23 INF
MBR 20200

what is code of the first line of mark **B23 INF**
in this MBR 20200 diode

Comment: B23 is the package: https://www.web-bcs.com/chips/b/chip_list_b13.php

Comment: Nonok a photograph is absolutely needed here. Manufacturer's logo and package shape is very important. Also be prepared to measure some critical dimensions.